# Redirection Problem. From ‘My Account’ as well as from ‘Checkout Page’

Tags: magento-1.7

I have store on which i am having the category for my product . on Home page my link to product is 
www.example-site.com/product_sold.html but when i go to my cart and from there i open category menu it will display  www.example-site.com/mycart/product_sold.html which will give me result not found can any tell me how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html and open topmenu.phtml file. find this code

```
<?php if($_menu): ?>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ol class="nav-primary">
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
        </ol>
    </nav>
<?php endif ?>
```

this code will output you the categories in the form of top menu if you don't use any categories hide this code or else paste this code before or after this code.

```
<ul>

               <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>your_page_uri">your_page_name</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>your_page_uri">your_page_name</a></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Actually i got this solution long time ago but with same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding two slashes at the start of the link will make it a 'Scheme Relative URI' and allow Magento to switch in and out of SSL and most likely alleviate the relative linking problem you are having.

See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503946/shorthand-http-as-for-script-and-link-tags-anyone-see-use-this-before

Comment: no luck to solve problem , if i flush cache it solve the problem but is not solution